# PostgreSQL клонирование пользователя

Tags: postgresql, psql

Встала задача по клонированию пользователей в postgres.
К примеру у меня есть пользователь Anna с правами на подключение к разным базам и схемам. Нужно создать пользователя Bob, ему же полностью передать все права от Anna и после удалить пользователя Anna.
Пробовал делать GRANT Anna TO Bob - это не помогло.
Прошу помощи у профессионалов

Comment: Исключено. как минимум потому, что перед удалением Anna придётся передать Bob владение теми объектами, которыми владела Anna, а это можно сделать только отдельным REASSIGN OWNED, который к тому же придётся запускать по отдельности в каждой схеме, где есть хоть что-то, чем владеет Anna.

Comment: Пользователь Anna не владеет чем либо. Так же как и остальные пользователи. Владельцы только специальные сервисные учетки

Comment: создать нового, дать права как, удалить... Да просто `alter user anna rename to bob;`

Comment: Это самый простой способ, но он не подходит. Идея в том что бы anna постепенно переехала на учетку bob. Т.е. в БД будут две одинаковые учетки, но с разными именами, и в последствии учетка anna будет заблокирована и скорее всего удалена

Comment: Но вообще можно попробовать по-простому - сначала `CREATE Bob INHERITS Anna`, а потом `ALTER Anna NOLOGIN`. И пусть себе висит как группа. Переименовать разве что...

Comment: Спасибо. А что если попробовать "скопировать" все права Anna и передать их Bob? Как это можно ещё сделать не прибегая к наследованию?